# How to share cloudformation or cdk with shared development infrastructure?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I asked question about how to code cost-efficient way with CDK in here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71836274/what-is-the-cost-efficient-approach-for-aws-serverless-team-development?noredirect=1#comment127052075_71836274

But the question is closed with [Questions related to pricing or costs of services are not acceptable here].

https://stackoverflow.com/users/405555/elliveny and
https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein

advised me to share a single account for developers and I did.

But now my team says if they create 2 separate branches and deploy, they are overwriting each other's work on AWS.

1. developer A creates branchA from develop
2. developer B creates branchB from develop
3. developer A develops API (appsync + lambda)
4. developer b develops API (appsync + lambda)
5. developer A deploy branchA
6. developer B deploy branchB

and on aws developer A work is overwritten. only developer B work stays.

my question :

1. Is this how aws cloudformation work? or our team doing something wrong?
2. if yes, on what level does it overwrite? for example if it is stack level, we can make `[2 developer chan't change same cdk stack same time]` rule

Comment: This has nothing to do with CDK but with how you manage infrastructure for multiple envs

Comment: Sorry. my question was a little confusing. 

That is exactly what I want to know. How do you guys manage your development infrastructure for 10 developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of recurses they are using in their branches. If the resources are regional such as lambda and API gateway, then they can depoly their branches to **different regions**. CloudFormation is regional, so they will not clash with each other.

But ideally, the developers A and B should have their **own sandbox accounts** for testing and development for maximum separation. Once their branches gets merged into `master` (or equivalent) then you, and only you, deploy these changes to a dedicated test/development account for further testing.

Comment: I see. Then the best approach is 10 developers 10 accounts 10 separate infra.

It may cost 10 times but it is faster and safer.

Comment: @matar No - the best approach is i.e. development, pre-production & production. Maybe even sandbox there.

Comment: OK. I try to make sure CDK is not overwriting other deployments.

Maybe We are failing to properly sync git code. We will check our git flow again.